# Type must accept all properties except some of them in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have to overload a type to forbidden some properties, so I cannot update the original type, and must create a new one.
I could create a new type but that must accept every properties EXCEPT some.

```
type Foo = {
    [key: string]: any
}

type ForbiddenProperties = "a";

type Test = Foo & { [key in ForbiddenProperties]: never }  // AtMostOneOf<Foo>;

const test: Test = {a: 1}; // Must NOT Work
const test1: Test = {b: 'asd'}; // Must Work
const test2: Test = {a: 1, b: 'asd'}; // Must NOT Work
const test3: Test = {} // Must Work
```

The `Foo` type is the original, and the `Test` is the new one.

Of course if the `Foo` would be easier like

```
type Foo = {
    a: string,
    b: string,
}
```

It would work fine, but not, the index signatures return errors everytime.

If the `a` property exist, the error is fine, but if there no forbiddenProperty, typescript ask me to ADD the missing property

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Test'.
  Property 'a' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ a: never; }'.
```

To play with it, there is a (playground)[https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.3.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUDaBrCEALigGdgAnASwDsBzAXRIEMaR0BfddUSWOCgCMqAExEQaABQpxIFYFQilkUAETNVAbm69oAFSXAV8RADI0uAiCi1+Q0eKky5CpUyg0IANwgUoHLAB6QKgAQWAAWThyAHlPGIAzAB4TAD5tdABjOBpyKGBDEgM8lFRmEgBGDk0oYKgIgFc8gDkYvSgAdQE8LJy8gvIKosMVVEESAHJmUhEJ6tqQxryuih7s3KMB4AAmYZK0cqgKgBoocagpmbmauqWjVvaVtb7NwwBmPaNSgNumoyfuOggA
]

I try a lot of things, like exclude explicitly

```
type Foo = {
   [key: Exclude<string, 'a'>]: string
}
```

But all properties, even the forbidden one

If you have an idea.

Comment: You should make it an *optional* property of type `never`, like `{ [K in ForbiddenProperties]?: never }`. See the answer to the linked question for more information.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz 
That's perfect... to be optional -_- so obvious!